# Executing a terminal command during UI test

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

While running a UI test in Xcode 8, I would like to run a command (such as ssh into a server) using the NSTask/Process class to verify that the server processed the UI command successfully. However, I get the following error when trying to use the Process/NSTask class:

'Use of unresolved identifier 'Process' (Same error when trying to use NSTask).

Is there any workaround to this? Thank you!

Comment: Is this a UI test for an iOS app? Those APIs aren't accessible on iOS.

Comment: You should have separate functional tests for your server. Anything being tested at the UI level should be testable using results accessible to the end user.